# Unable to set the order status after sales_order_save_after

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order, order-status

I want to check my order and if my order has any back order items i want to set the order status as Back orders(My custom status code is `backorders`).

My **config.xml** `<events>` section is : -

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after> <!-- observe the event -->
        <observers>
            <stainless_backorders>
                <class>stainless_backorders/observer</class>
                <method>updateOrderStatus</method>
            </stainless_backorders>
        </observers>    
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

My **Observer.php** file contains below codes :-

```
public function updateOrderStatus($observer) {

    $orderId = $observer->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
    $order      = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();              
    $backorder_status = '';

     foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
         $item->getProduct()->getProductId();
         $itemQtyBackordered = intval($item->getQtyBackordered());
         $orderedQty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
         $totalQty = (int)$item->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getQty();

        if($itemQtyBackordered>0){
            $backorder_status = 1;
        }
     }
     if($backorder_status==1){                          
        $order->setStatus("backorders");        
        $order->save();
     }
}
```

If i use `$order->setStatus("backorders");` this line to change the status i am getting an error like below[image] and if i use this line the observer function is calling several times, why is this?

If i comment this line only one time its reachinf this method.

My question is , Is my approach is right? In wich stage an orders status is saved in the magento database?
If not how can i do this task?

**UPDATE : My config.xml**

```
<sales>
      <order>
        <statuses>
          <backorders translate="label">
            <label>Back Orders</label>
          </backorders>
        </statuses>
        <states>
          <backorders translate="label">
            <label>Back Orders</label>
            <statuses>
              <backorders default="1"/>
            </statuses>
          </backorders>
        </states>
      </order>
</sales>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code    and change event `sales_order_save_commit_after`

```
$order->setData('state', 'backorders');
$order->setStatus('backorders');
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);                 
$history->setStatus('backorders')->setData('state', 'backorders')->setIsCustomerNotified(false);               
$order->save();
```

make you define your state in etc/config.xml

```
<global>
    <sales>
      <order>
        <states>
        <backorders translate="label">
          <label>backorders</label>
            <statuses>
                <backorders default="1"/>
            </statuses>
          <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
        </backorders>
      </states>
      </order>
    </sales>
```

Comment: @mujas any error in error log?

Comment: @mujas update the code it working for me many time make sure order in loaded.

Comment: i wil try , you also using the same event "sales_order_save_after"?

Comment: yes, I only miss the <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front> this part only.

Comment: @mujas i am using this code  `$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
                         $order->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);$history = $invoice->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment(
       'created invoice', true
   );$order->save();` and yes the same event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50515/discussion-between-mujas-and-fme-extensions).

Comment: same error coming after changed the event too

Answer (score 0):

you can increase your stack limit from `php.ini` file in your **xampp/wampp** server to whatever you want or you can disable it by comment it.

May be it helps you.

Comment: Thank you.I think that is not my issue,i changed it to 1000 and also comment it too, I am some where behind some magento process miss behavior. may be my approach is wrong.its only come when i call $order->setStatus("backorders");

Comment: How can i change auto status changes. i need to show awaiting shipment after click shipment instead of completed

Comment: @JeevaRathinam that you have to write a module with the relevant event called via observer you can update it.To add new order status you can use the same module by writing an mysql script

Comment: could you pls explain briefly pls..

Comment: @mujas try to set the other status rather than this one with the state like `$order_->setState("processing")->setStatus("processing");`. Also check your status in the order status config.

Comment: @NitinPawar : may i get briefly explain

Comment: @NitinPawar thank you.But i want to update with my custom state and status(backorders).what do you mean by order status config?

Comment: @JeevaRathinam your question is different. pls post a separate question will answer it there.

Comment: verify your custom status config, is it correct. May be you are using different  name.

Comment: @NitinPawar :   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151429/how-can-i-change-auto-status-changes-i-need-to-show-awaiting-shipment-after-cli

Comment: @mujas : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151429/how-can-i-change-auto-status-changes-i-need-to-show-awaiting-shipment-after-cli

Comment: @NitinPawar i added this new status using $installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
        $statusStateTable,
        array('status', 'state', 'is_default'),
            array(
                array(
                    'status' => 'backorders', 
                    'state' => 'backorders', 
                    'is_default' => 1
                )
            )
        );

Comment: after even comment this line xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100 in php.ini the same error is comng