# How can i change auto status changes. I need to show awaiting shipment after click shipment instead of completed

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, autocomplete

I need to set awaiting shipment after shipment clicked instead of complete.

Comment: @Manashvibirla : make sure after ship clicked status changed awaiting shipment, right after manually change "complete"

Answer (score 1):

Creating shipment of an order in Magento changes the order status to **Complete** and state **complete** while invoice is already created. So first you need to create a new order status **awaiting shipment** and assign it to **complete state** from admin **System > Order Statuses**.

Now admin can change the order status manually from order edit detail spage bottom left comment section.

But, I guess you are looking for any automated code solution.
So here the deal is, you need to use order save after event to change the order status.

You need to use the event `sales_order_shipment_save_after` and in your observer method you need to get the order and change the order status and save.
The event is defined at

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php`

```
protected function _afterSave()
{
    $this->cleanModelCache();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_after', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

here `$this->_eventPrefix` is `sales_order_shipment` defined at

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php`

In your observer method, you need use method `setState` from order model `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to save your newly created save.

```
public function setState($state, $status = false, $comment = '', $isCustomerNotified = null)
{
    return $this->_setState($state, $status, $comment, $isCustomerNotified, true);
}
```

I assume you have experience in M1 development. Dont forget to post comment if you need more help on this.